# Solve for $\beta$. (Series)

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, statistics, linear-regression

I am proving the least squares estimates of the regression coefficients and I've come across these 2 equations.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i=\alpha n+\beta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_i=\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+\beta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2$$

I am supposed to solve what is $\beta$. The answer given is $$\beta=\frac{n(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i)-(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i)}{n(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2)-(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^2}$$

I've tried many times to work it out by substitution method. But failed. 
It's tedious.

Hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i &= \alpha n+\beta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i  \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_i &= \alpha \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+\beta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2
\end{align*}
Multiply the first by $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$ and the second by $n$ to make the terms containing $\alpha$ match.
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i &= \alpha n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i + \beta  \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \right)^2 \\
n \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_i &= \alpha n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i + \beta n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2
\end{align*}
Subtract the first from the second, which cancels the $\alpha$ terms.
$$  n \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i
= \beta n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - \beta  \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \right)^2 $$
Now factor out the common $\beta$ on the right-hand side and divide to isolate it.
$$  n \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i
= \beta \left( n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \right)^2 \right) $$
and then 
$$  \frac{n \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_i - \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{n \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \right)^2 }
= \beta  \text{.}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your equation system is from the form
$$A=\alpha n+\beta B$$
$$C=\alpha B+\beta D$$
from the first equation we get
$$\alpha=\frac{C-\beta D}{B}$$ plugging this in the second equation:
$$A=\frac{C-\beta D}{B}\cdot n+\beta B$$ multiplying by $B$:
$$AB=Cn-\beta Dn+\beta B^2$$
so we have
$$\beta=\frac{AB-Cn}{B^2-Dn}$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. You may divide each term of your two equalities by $n$, obtaining
$$
\begin{cases} \alpha+\bar{x}\beta=\bar{y} \\ \bar{x}\alpha+\bar{x^2}\beta=\sigma_{xy}\end{cases}
$$ which is a standard system of linear equations to solve.

Here we have just set
$$
\bar{x}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}n, \quad \bar{y}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i}n
$$ and
$$
\bar{x^2}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x^2_i}n, \quad \sigma_{xy}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i}n.
$$

Answer (score 3):

It is because your keep the orginal notations.

Rewrite $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i=\alpha n+\beta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_ix_i=\alpha \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i+\beta \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2$$
as
$$S_1=n\alpha+S_2\beta$$
$$S_3=S_2\alpha+S_4\beta$$ Now, eliminate $\alpha$ from the first, replace in the second and solve it for $\beta$.

Answer (score 2):

Use Cramer's Rule.

\begin{align}
\Delta &= \begin{vmatrix} n & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 \end{vmatrix} \\
\Delta_\alpha &= \begin{vmatrix} \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i \\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 \end{vmatrix} \\
\Delta_\beta &= \begin{vmatrix} n & \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i \\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i & \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i \end{vmatrix} \\
\alpha &= \frac{\Delta_\alpha}{\Delta} = \frac{(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2) - (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i)}{n(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2) - (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^2} \\
\beta &= \frac{\Delta_\beta}{\Delta} = \frac{n(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_iy_i) - (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)(\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i)}{n(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2) - (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^2}
\end{align}

Comment: I never know it can be solved by cramer's rule! Thanks!

Comment: @Mathxx Its a system of linear equation, what else you did expect?

Answer (score 1):

It's clearer to use the following notation: 
$$S_x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i, \qquad 
S_y=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i,\qquad 
S_{xy}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i,\qquad 
S_{xx}=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$
Thus we have

$$\begin{align}
S_y&=\alpha n\;\ +\beta S_x\tag{1}\\
S_{xy}&=\alpha S_x\ +\beta S_{xx}\tag{2}\\
\\
\alpha=\frac {S_y-\beta S_x}n&=\frac {S_{xy}-\beta S_{xx}}{S_x}\\\\
\beta(S_{xx}-S_x)&=nS_{xy}-S_xS_y\\\\
\beta&=\frac {nS_{xy}-S_xS_y}{S_{xx}-S_x}\end{align}$$
which expands to the required result.